# Eventos click jquery en iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, click

Buen día, he estado batallando con los eventos click de jQuery y iOS. He probado varias soluciones, pero no funcionan. La primera que probé fue agregarle a los elementos en los que tengo los eventos el tipo de cursor a "pointer". Pero no funciona.

```
.clickeable {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Después implemente la detección del dispositivo iOS y cambiar los eventos de click a touchstart

```
var user_agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var event = user_agent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/)  ? "touchstart" : "click"; 
$("#menu-toggle").bind(event,function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#menu-toggle').tooltip('hide');
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    $("#menubtn")
 });
```

Esto hacía funcionar solo el botón de menú, pero otros eventos no funcionan. Como este:

```
$('.animadoespecial').bind(event,function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top -100
   }, 500);
});
```

También probé agregando el atributo onClick, pero nada funciona.

```
$('#menu-toggle').attr('onclick', '');
```

¿Qué podrá ser?

Comment: ¿Quieres decir que no te funcionan los eventos cuando haces click?

Comment: si, ya edite un poco

Comment: tengo una función `$( "#slider-simulador" ).on( "slidestop", function( event, ui ) { actualizacionAPVSlider(); } );` que al presionarla el dispositivo hace focus al final de la página (pasa solo la primera vez que presiono el slider)

Answer (score 1):

> Ten en cuenta que: por lo general, en dispositivos móviles el evento `touchstart` se dispara **inmediatamente** después de haberse producido el *toque*, mientras que el evento `click` se dispara **300ms** después. Si mezclas éstos es posible te encuentres con el problema del *[click fantasma](http://ariatemplates.com/blog/2014/05/ghost-clicks-in-mobile-browsers/)*.

Ésto está mal:

```
$('.animadoespecial').bind(event,function (event) { ... });
```

El primer parámetro debe ser el *tipo de evento* que se quiere asociar al elemento. El segundo, el callback a ejecutar cuando suceda. Lo anterior debería ser:

```
// o touchstart
$('.animadoespecial').bind('click', function (event) { ... });
```

¿Qué significa ésto?

```
$('#menu-toggle').attr('onclick', '');
```

No tiene ningún sentido. Solo estás estableciendo un string vacío al atributo `onclick` del elemento.

---

**Nota:** Éste método ha sido marcado como *deprecated* en la versión 3.x. Se recomienda usar `on` en su lugar:

```
// o touchstart
$('.animadoespecial').on('click', function (event) { ... });
```